# Access Chrome extension from another computer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I coded a little app for Chrome, it's a privacy extension and I want to be able to access it from outside my computer. I read a lot of thing about contents scripts but I don't know if is the way to go. In my extension I have a option.html file and I want to be able to access it if I'm not at home. The file is actually stored on Chrome tabs when I open it. I want to access it but only from my domain, all request must be not executed. Do I have to make a websocket on my extension? Or can I put an iframe into my option.html and read it from a server side with php script?

Comment: "the file is stored in chrome tabs" makes no sense to mr.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the folder into a .crx type.Visit https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting for more info

Comment: Hi, i come back because i don't find yet a good and poper way to do what i want.